# react navigation v6, prevent swipe back event between stack navigator

Tags: react-navigation

I have nested navigator structure.

Root

- MainTab - MailBox Screen
- MainStack
- SignUp Stack - Name/NickName Screen - PhoneNumberScreen - Confirm Screen

when i navigate to SignUp Stack from MainBox Screen, i dont want go back to mailbox screen when swipe back event on confirm screen.

i try to use gestureEnabled: false.

how can i prevent swipe event between navigator ?

I try to use gestureEnabled: false, getParent().setOptions({ gestureEnabled: false }) inside useEffect.